# Checking file count for a particular format in a directory in unix

Tags: shell

I want to know the file count for a particular format like **.txt** in a particular directory

Comment: Recursively or not?

Answer (score 2):

You can do, from that directory:

```
files=( *.txt )
echo "${#files[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
ls -l *.txt | wc -l
```

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls

Comment: does it match filenames staring with "." ?

Comment: @MunaiDasUdasin `bash` doesn't glob dot-files unless you specify `shopt -s dotglob`, so no, it doesn't

Comment: @don_crissti of course you can parse the output of `ls`, or even use `eval` properly. The point is, you often have simpler and more robust ways to do what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

A portable approach, which also handles strange filenames (for example with newlines in it), dot-files (filename starts with a `.`) and other special characters like quotes (only the current directory):

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.txt" -print0 | tr -cd '\0' | wc -c
```

Or recursively (without `-maxdepth`), will count files in subdirectories too:

```
find -type f -iname "*.txt" -print0 | tr -cd '\0' | wc -c
```

---

Explanation:

- `-maxdepth 1` search inly in the current directory, don't descend into subdirectories.
- `-type f` search only regular files.
- `-iname "*.txt"` search for files with ending txt case-insensitive.
- `-print0` this is the important part, delimit the list by the null byte character
- `tr -cd '\0'` removes everything except the null byte character.
- `wc -c` counts the number of characters (which is now the number of files)

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way:

```
ls /path/to/directory | grep ".txt$" | wc -l
```

If you want search to include subdirectories:

```
ls -lR /path/to/directory | grep ".txt$" | wc -l
```

Other way is:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | wc -l
```